# How do I change the height of an iOS extension?

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios10, ios-extensions

How do I change the height of an iOS 10 extension in compact mode? Or more broadly, how do I change the height of an extension without using `widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange`?

Comment: Rewording for clarity and ease of reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

Here is the solution to your problem:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        
    self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width:self.view.frame.size.width, height:210)
        
    if #available(iOSApplicationExtension 10.0, *) {
        self.extensionContext?.widgetLargestAvailableDisplayMode = .expanded
    }
}
```

the height as 210 how I prefer, you can use any height of course...

## Update

If you want to use a fixed size you can use NCWidgetDisplayMode's second option "compact":

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
public enum NCWidgetDisplayMode : Int {    
    case compact // Fixed height
    case expanded // Variable height
}
```

you can update your code like below :

```
if #available(iOSApplicationExtension 10.0, *) {
    self.extensionContext?.widgetLargestAvailableDisplayMode = .compact
}
```

Comment: this works but i want to change height of widget without using showmore/showless

Comment: @NohaMohamed please check my updated answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: it works successfully , thanks . Can i hide showmore button and change height ?

Comment: you can use widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange:(NCWidgetDisplayMode)activeDisplayMode withMaximumSize:(CGSize)maxSize for change height because compact will make a default (very small) size for your extension.